# How do I copy cells next to cells with a certain value and paste them somewhere else

Tags: excel, vba

In cells I28:L42 I have some data, and in Column L it will say either "Pending" or "Issued"

I am trying to create some VBA that finds where cells in Column L say "Issued", and then copy the three cells to the left of it from Col I:K, and paste them in the first available cell in Column AP:AR, and repeat for all rows in my range that say "Issued"

I have built some VBA that seems to be working with two issues that I can't figure out how to solve. I am super new to this, so I have built what I have so far from suggestions on the internet, but can't figure out how to combine questions to fix the issues I am coming across.

My code looks like it is finding the cells next to the cell that says issued and copying them, but then it pastes it 15 times in the first available rows in Col AP:AR. (This is the number of rows in my initial search range so I think that is why, but I don't know how to ask the code to only paste once for each one). The other issue is that I get an error if no rows say "issued", and I'm not exactly sure how to build in that error handling.

```
Sub IssuedPolicies()
Set SearchRng = Range("L28:L42")
Dim IssuedRange As Range
Dim IssuedCell As Range
    For Each Cell In SearchRng
    If Cell.Value = "Issued" Then Set IssuedCell = Cell
    Set IssuedRange = Range(IssuedCell.Offset(0, -3), IssuedCell.Offset(0, -1))
    IssuedRange.Copy
    Dim Target As Range
    Set Target = Range("AP" & rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Target.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Next Cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `IssuedRange` is not necessary.
- The logic of `If Cell.Value = "Issued" Then` is incorrect. Next line may raise run-time error if cell value isn't `Issued`.
- Directly setting cells' value is more efficient than copy / paste.

Please try.

```
Sub IssuedPolicies()
    Dim SearchRng As Range
    Set SearchRng = Range("L28:L42")
    Dim IssuedRange As Range
    Dim Cell As Range, Target As Range
    For Each Cell In SearchRng
        If Cell.Value = "Issued" Then
            Set IssuedRange = Cell.Offset(0, -3).Resize(1, 3)
            Set Target = Range("AP" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 3)
            Target.Value = IssuedRange.Value
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Lookup Data

[image]

**Assumptions**

To simplify the code, the following assumptions are made:

- The single-column lookup range has more than one row or else `slData` will be no array.
- The first source (copy) and destination (paste) columns have no empty cells at the bottom or else `End(xlUp)` might fail and existing data may be overwritten, if not sooner, then when calling the method another time.

**The Calling Procedure (Usage)**

```vb
Sub IssuedPolicies()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    MatchData ws, "L28:L42", "I:K", "AP", "Issued"

End Sub
```

**The Called Procedure (The Method)**

```vb
Sub MatchData( _
        ByVal ws As Worksheet, _
        ByVal LookupSingleColumnRange As String, _
        ByVal CopyColumns As String, _
        ByVal FirstPasteColumn As String, _
        ByVal LookupString As String)
    Const PROC_TITLE As String = "Match Data"
    
    Dim slData(), cData()
    
    With ws.Range(LookupSingleColumnRange)
        slData = .Value
        cData = .EntireRow.Columns(CopyColumns).Value
    End With
    
    Dim srCount As Long: srCount = UBound(cData, 1)
    Dim cCount As Long: cCount = UBound(cData, 2)
    
    Dim sr As Long, dr As Long, c As Long
    
    For sr = 1 To srCount
        If StrComp(CStr(slData(sr, 1)), LookupString, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            dr = dr + 1
            For c = 1 To cCount
                cData(dr, c) = cData(sr, c)
            Next c
        End If
    Next sr
    
    If dr = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No matching data found.", vbExclamation, PROC_TITLE
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim dCell As Range:
    Set dCell = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, FirstPasteColumn).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dCell.Resize(dr, cCount)
    
    drg.Value = cData
    
    MsgBox "Data matches retrieved.", vbInformation, PROC_TITLE

End Sub
```